# Nation_script_load.sh asks for the DB password for each step

Tags: postgis, geocoding, tiger

I'm loading TIGER geocoder data with the nation_script_load, during the process, I have to type the password several times. The same password that I set earlier along with the paths.

```
export PGPASSWORD= "my_password"
```

Is this normal or can I avoid to type/paste the password each time?

Comment: It shouldn't be prompting unless the password is wrong.  Try removing the space between the = and "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in bash, you can set a variable in this way:

```
PGPASSWORD=mypassword
```

without any space aroud the equal sign.

If you are using Postgresql, usually there is a fila called .pgpass under you profile root (/home/user/.pgpass). This file contains the various connections saved with the password.
If you use the same combination how host and user, psql read from the file the password.

Answer (score 2):

Try removing the double quotes.

I'm not sure about the unix environment, but none of string type system environment variables on windows have double quotes around them.